# $(\ker \phi)^\perp = \text {constant }$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $\psi$ be a scalar product defined on polynomials by $\psi(f(t),g(t)) =\int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)dt  $.

Let $f$ and $g$ be real polynomials and consider the linear application given by $\phi(f(t))=\int_{-1}^1f(t)dt$. We want to show that $(\ker \phi)^\perp = \mathbb R_0 (\text {constants})$. I chose to do it with double inclusion, I've already showed that $\mathbb R_0 \subseteq (\ker \phi)^\perp$ now to show that $(\ker \phi)^\perp \subseteq \mathbb R_0$,  I need to show that if $$\forall f(t), \int_{-1}^1f(t)dt = 0 \text { and } \int_{-1}^1f(t)g(t)dt = 0 \implies g'(t)= 0$$

I wanted to the integration by parts but I don't find the result I want, can someone help me ?

Comment: What are your conditions on $f$ and $g$ ? Continuous ? Differentiable ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that $f$ and $g$ are real polynomials, sorry

Comment: could you edit your question?

Comment: @Falcon yes I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, we are assuming that $$\int^1_{-1}f(t)g(t) = 0$$ for all $f$ such that $\int^1_{-1} f(t) dt = 0$, and we want to then conclude that $g$ must be constant.

Assume that $g(t)$ has this property and take any $f(t)$ such that $\int^1_{-1}f(t) dt = 0$. Then we see that $$0 = \int^1_{-1} f(t)g(t) dt = \int^1_{-1} f(t)[g(t) - g_{\text{avg}}] dt \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, (*)$$ where $g_{\text{avg}} = \frac 1 2\int^1_{-1} g(s) ds$ is a constant (the average value of $g$ on the interval). Since equation $(*)$ holds for any such $f(t)$, we can take in particular $f(t) = g(t) - g_{\text{avg}}$ since this function integrates to $0$. Plugging this in gives $$0 = \int^1_{-1} [g(t) - g_{\text{avg}}]^2dt.$$ But this is possible iff $g(t) = g_{\text{avg}}$ for all $t \in [-1,1]$. This proves that $g$ is constant.